# How to have a click-able button in my combo-box ItemTemplate?

Tags: wpf, combobox, datatemplate, items

This is what i have so far:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Name="cboUserCustomReports"
                      Width="300" Height="Auto"
                      Margin="0,5,0,5"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserReportProfileList,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      EditValue="{Binding Path=UserReportProfileID,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      ValueMember="UserReportProfileID"
                      DisplayMember="ReportName"
                      PopupClosed="cboUserCustomReports_PopupClosed">
            <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                   Text="{Binding ReportName, Mode=Default}" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <Button Name="btnDelete" 
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Width="20" Height="20"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                Click="btnDelete_Click">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="/RMSCommon;component/Resources/Delete.ico"></Image>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
        </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
```

First, i want the two columns to be stand alone. The user must be able to select or delete the item.

Second, i would like to make my button in the ItemTemplate to be click-able.

What do i need to add to get this behavior?

This is what it looks like at the moment:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Click**
I assume, that your button is clickable, and you want to know how to process the click event. Right?
For the click-handler, add the following code:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    FrameworkElement fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
    if(null == fe){
        return;
    }
    UserReportProfile userReportProfile = fe.DataContext as UserReportProfile;
    if (null == userReportProfile) {
        return;
    }
    // Do here your deletion-operation

}
```

I assumed that your item-class is named UserReportProfile. Otherwise, change the declared type accordingly.

**Layout**
For the alignment, add the following declaration to your ComboBox:

```
HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
```

This gives your DataTemplate-Grid the full width and you can layout then your items as you desire.

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Name="cboUserCustomReports"                         
      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"            
      Width="300" Height="Auto"                         
      Margin="0,5,0,5"   
      ...>
```

Comment: The layout part worked perfectly. thx. Now for the button. The button is not clickable, so how do i approach it?

Comment: The problem lies IMO in the control template of the button. To start, remove the Template of the button. Make the image a content-part of the button. This is not so nice as your solution (the border will be shown) but then you can develop your deletion logic. When you have finished the deletion logic, google for "ControlTemplate Button WPF" to find an example on how creating a control template for the button. Another (cheap) possibility would be to process the PreviewMouseDown on the image, but I would not recommend to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough. But I guess you want to vertically align the *text* and *images* in your combobox. If so, then all you need to do this:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

And I think your items are already clickable!

Comment: @Nawaz: This makes no big difference, 100* is the same as * and 20 is the fixed width that quasi equals to "Auto". The point here is the "HorizontalContentAlignment=Stretch" However using "Auto" is in deed better than the fixed width...

Comment: @HCL: But just `*` is enough for the purpose. The actual thing that one needs to pay attention to is : `Auto`.

Comment: @Willem: If it solved your problem satisfactorily, then accept it as solution to your problem!

Comment: @Nawaz: No, definitively no, in his example, you will not see any difference between auto and 20, because he has defined the width of the control explicitely to 20. It's only a question of cleanness. Moreover can it be also meaningfull to declare a fixed width in the column definition, because the auto-value can can give serious performance penalties in complex grids. But in this example, this will definively not happen.

Comment: @HCL: I would like to hear from him if only doing this solves his problem or not.

Comment: okay. the fixed width and Auto had the same outcome. The only aspact that solved my alignment problem was HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch".